# Trying to get lowest value before comma from string using explode

Tags: php

I am new to php but learning fast. I am trying to extract the lowest price from a string of values like -

```
"12/6/2020:Some Text:345.44,13/6/2020:Some Text:375.88,14/6/2020:Some Text:275.81"
```

I need to get the value just before each comma and then get the lowest of these values. I know I can use min() if I get these values in a string. For the above example I need 275.81 (lowest).

Please see my code below. I am trying to explode the values and then put in a string. I dont think this is the best way by far and not having any luck. is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

```
$dates = explode(',', $resultx);
foreach($dates as $datew) {
$dater = explode(':', $datew);
echo $dater[2]. ",";
}
```

Comment: It's hard to see what this has to do with mysql, or indeed any relational database management system

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions to extract the values, and then use min() to get the minimum value

```
<?php

$input = "2/6/2020:Some Text:345.44,13/6/2020:Some Text:375.88,14/6/2020:Some Text:275.81";
$pattern = '/(?:[^\:]+)\:(?:[^\:]+)\:(\d+\.\d+)\,*/';
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches)) {
    $minimumValue = min($matches[1]);
    echo "minimum is: " . $minimumValue;
}
```

Here is a working example on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/82BW8)

In the pattern `(?:[^\:]+)` - equals any symbol, except the colon `:`

Section `(\d+\.\d+)` says that we need to capture the sequence containing two numbers with a dot `.` between them.

We look for two sections with any symbols, except `:`, and then capturing the third sections containing numbers, and everything ends with an optional comma `,`

P.S. you could still get the result with your current approach

```
<?php

$input = "2/6/2020:Some Text:345.44,13/6/2020:Some Text:375.88,14/6/2020:Some Text:275.81";
$minimumValue = null;
$dates = explode(',', $input);
foreach($dates as $datew) {
    $dater = explode(':', $datew);
    $currentValue = floatval($dater[2]);
    if (is_null($minimumValue) || $minimumValue > $currentValue) {
        $minimumValue = $currentValue;
    }
}

echo $minimumValue;
```

Here is a link to your approach on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/jB1B6)

Comment: Sorry to be cheeky, but any ideas on how I could count the groups between each comma and show the number of the group the lowest price is in? eg. 275.81 - 3 (3 being the group number) tks

Comment: `array_search($minimumValue , $matches[1])` will return a group index. Add 1 to make it a group number.